# Is there a way to hyperlink the slices in a pie chart of a sharepoint(google visualization) web part?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, google-visualization

I am working with Microsoft Sharepoint and Google Analytics - Visualization integration.
Currently I have a pie chart. My question is whether there is a way to hyperlink the slices in the chart, so that they could be linked to a specific object and is there a way of organizing the legend in the format of biggest slice to the lowest?

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming QA site. If there's no code involved you may be better off asking this question in another site. Maybe a Sharepoint related site.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Google Chart tools library you can have Pie charts that are selectable.

All you have to do is listen for the `select` [Event on the Pie Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Events). Than use the `getSelection()` method from Pie Chart to get the selected row. Than you go back to your dataTable and get the data you want based on the selected row.

```js
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work', 11],
    ['Eat', 2],
    ['Commute', 2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep', 7]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization'))
  chart.draw(data, {title:"So, how was your day?"});
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(){
    var row = chart.getSelection()[0].row;
    var element = data.getValue(row, 0);
    alert('You just selected: ' + element);
  });
}
​
```

example:

http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/?id=7b92cc41120837bc319a69144925122670167cd7

In my example I only alert the value selected. But you can use javascript to redirect the user to a different page:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';
```

Comment: Can you hyperlink the legends instead of the pie chart itself, do you think that would be easier?

Comment: I am deriving the information from a different list, how do you think I should go about hyperlinking each element with the right data?

Comment: The select event fires for both the legend and the chart area. @user1397695 I have no idea what you mean on your second question, you should either post a new question or edit your question to include more info.

Comment: So basically I have an excel master list inside sharepoint which is where the information is coming from. suppose i have a list of fruits sales and i want to see how many apples were sold. How can I hyperlink the view which I have made (that consists of just apple sales).

Comment: @user1397695 I don't know nothing about sharepoint. I can only help you with Google Charts related questions.

Comment: I got the views in, but for some reason not all the data show i.e. if the data has jan, feb, march sales of apples and oranges. it does not show March for oranges. Any idea why that would be so? It's leaving the last data series off. Is there a bug in the API or something wrong with my format?